# Way to simplify functions?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to create a class or something that can contain all these different textboxes. I just want to know if this is the most efficient way I can code this.

```
private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }


        private void textBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox2.Text = "";
        }

        private void textBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox3.Text = "";
        }
        private void textBox4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox4.Text = "";
        }
        private void textBox5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox5.Text = "";
        }
```

Comment: Well if they are all the same code you could just have one function handling all those events. You would do `((TextBox)sender).Text = "";`

Answer (score 5):

Don't create *separated* event handlers for *each* `TextBox`es. Instead, create a *combined* event for *all* the `TextBoxes`: `textBox1..textBox5`.

Then

```
private void textBoxs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is TextBox box) box.Text = "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the event handler to all the TextBoxes on load, eg

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    foreach(var tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        tb.Click += (sender, eventArgs) => ((TextBox)sender).Text = "";
    }
}
```